# Using Brand Names as our Customers for advertising

Tags: copyright, trademark, india, advertisements, branding

I am the owner of a marketing business, **XYZ Solutions (Ind) Pvt. Ltd**.

Now, I want to increase my sales so can I use Brand Names like Amazon, Flipkart, Ebay, Google, etc as my customers in my Website? (Though they are not!)

---

**UPDATE**

I am the owner of a marketing business, **XYZ Solutions (Ind) Pvt. Ltd**.

As I just started the company I have Two or Three Advertisers and Affiliates Marketing of Amazon, Flipkart, Ebay, etc.

Now, I want to increase my sales so can I use Affiliates Marketing's name: Amazon, Flipkart, Ebay, etc as my customers in my Website?

Comment: "Though they are not!" That's called fraud.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's inane.

Comment: Just have a look at the updated question...

Comment: It is still not at all clear to me what you are asking. Id thre a **legal** problem with increasing your business or advertising it?  you write *Now, I want to increase my sales so can I use Affiliates Marketing's name: Amazon, Flipkart, Ebay, etc as my customers in my Website?* How do you plan to do that? What legal issue are you facing that you want to know about? Remember that we cannot act as your lawyer and give specific legal advice, nor can we give specific business plan advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you advertise that various well-known firms are clients of yours, when this is in fact a lie, this is a form of [false advertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_advertising). If other clients or potential clients reasonably rely on those false statements and suffer harm by doing so, it might also be a form of fraud. Most jurisdictions have some form of government sanctions on false advertising, which may include injunctions to stop such ads, and fines for ones already published. In some cases, criminal penalties could apply. This would be a very unwise course of action, and announcing it here only provides evidence that such false statements are made knowingly.

Comment: Just have a look at the updated question...